# Statistical Significance level - elementary level

Tags: statistics

Let's say one day my sister tells me she has psychic powers and can help me predict the winners in horse racing games and for whatever reason, we only have 2 horse racers in a game. She tells me that if she chooses 'blue', then the blue horse wins (painted blue okay?) and if she chooses 'red', then the red horse wins. She does this $8$ times and it turns out she was correct on all of them, making me very wealthy. Now is this a fluke or not? Let's test this at a significance level of $\alpha = 0.05$

Assuming my sister isn't really a psychic, then I expect she would be correct half the time. This yields $\mu = 4$. So my null hypothesis is $\mu = 4$ and my alternative would be $\mu = 8 > 4$. Let $X$ be the random variable denoting the "number of correct predictions my sister makes".

So $X \sim Bin(8,1/2)$

and I did $P(X = 8| \mu = 4) = (1/2)^8 \approx 0 < 0.05$. This leads me to conclude I should reject my initial null hypthosis and conclude my sister may be a psychic.

However this seems to go against any intuition since my sister is actually only 3 years old, and I probably made a Type I Error. Is this a correct analysis?

Comment: Is rejection of the null hypothesis $\mathcal{H}_0: \theta= 1/2$ really the same thing as concluding that she's a psychic? See this, for example: http://xkcd.com/1132/ :-)

Comment: I am not smart enough to understand the comic...

Comment: Is it because I can never "prove" she really is a psychic just because the null is wrong?

Comment: The alternative is not that she is a psychic. The alternative is that the parameter $\theta$ is larger than 1/2 (or, equivalently, that the mean $\mu=8\theta>4$). In general, you should be cautious when drawing conclusions form hypothesis tests. You reject the null - that is, you did not find enough evidence to accept the null. That does not mean you concluce that the alternative is necessarily true. And most importantly in this case, $\mu>4$ does not imply that she is a psychic.